# Kafka Rocks DB point to Amazon S3

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

Our dev team using Kafka stream java spring boot microservice, internally uses rocks dB . during cluster patching pod local storage are cleared. is it possible to point rocks dB to aws s3?

**state.backend.rocksdb.localdir**

Comment: That property is for Apache Flink, not Kafka Streams, and it is a _local_ directory, not remote/S3... If you want to run stateful Kafka Streams (or any stateful app) in k8s, you should have PVCs for the apps

Comment: @OneCricketeer: how to point stateful store to S3 bucket ,instead of PVC, during patching the pod is deleted and recreated.

Comment: RocksDB can only use local disk. If you want to us something else for the StateStore, implement the StateStore interface - https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/package-tree.html

Comment: Note: S3 is not a proper replacement for a Hashmap-like KV-Store. Instead you should consider using [redis](https://github.com/andreas-schroeder/redisks) or DynamoDB

Comment: I found this question and I was curious how it went with Streams State store, as I was trying to explore options like EFS, EBS or S3 for storing state instead of storing it in the local pod

Comment: @abdo_mah90: we did not try with s3 bucket yet. The state store is recovered from changelog topic.it solves problem for us.